# Outlook Add-In Custom form region and custom message class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook-addin

I am really new at outlook add-in development and I am struggling with concepts of outlook. For instance; creating form region with using custom message class. Actually I do not even know that is what I looking for. Please help me :) 
Here is the situation, I need to create a outlook add-in which has a folder and subfolders in it, in personal folders. Now so far so good. However What I need is when I click to that folder it opens a form (not window form) which is embedded to the outlook.

[image]

exactly like this example. I tried to separate and adjoining ones of form region but because of the IPM.standartMessageClass, it does not fit to me. I want to know How can I create this form and/or how can I create custom message class. 
I know it is not the concept of stackoverflow but I am really desperate :( Please Help me Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display an HTML page instead of the folder contents, the same when you right click on a folder and select "Properties | Home Page".

Try MAPIFolder.WebViewURL/WebViewOn properties.